# Is it possible to access form inputs which are looped with jinja2?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this form to answer a survey a user received in a html file.

```
<form method="POST" action="/answerSurvey">
  <ol>
    {% for q in questions %}
    <li>
      <label for="questionBody"><b>{{ q.body }}</b></label>
      <ul style="list-style: none;">
        {% for a in answers %}
        {% if q.id == a.question_id %}
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="{{ a.id }}"> {{ a.body }}</li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to create a function to receive the user input to see which questions got ticked. Something similar to

```
@app.route('/answerSurvey', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def answerSurvey():
    question_answers = request.form['something']
```

so I can store them in a database table with the associated answer.id.

Answer (score 1):

Well unfortunately I solved it a different way. Not the best, but it should be alright. All I did was adding the checkbox input with value 1. This will write 1 into the database, when the answer gets ticked. Since it only writes if there is something ticked, i needed to add a hidden input field, so the not ticked values are taken as well. The problem was, that when a user ticks an answer of a specific question it first creates the value one and additionally the value 0. Let's say There are two questions with two answers each. Then let's assume the first answer of each question is the correct one. I will then get the values [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]. Since I am not that great with JavaScript I used Python to solve my problem. I deleted the entries on the right of each 1.

This is my new code in html. It basically stores the values of the checkboxes in answers, which will change to a list when assigning multiple values. (I assume, it can also be that it always is a list) Anyways, when calling request.form I did use getList() to get all values from the checkboxes.

```
<form method="POST" action="/answerSurvey">
  <ol>
    {% for q in questions %}
    <li>
      <label for="questionBody"><b>{{ q.body }}</b></label>
      {% for a in answers %}
      {% if q.id == a.question_id %}
      <input type="checkbox" name="answers" id="answers" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="answers" id="answers-hidden" value="0">
      <label for="answers">{{ a.body }}</label>
      <br>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is the code in python. I am looping backwards since the list is getting smaller when deleting an item and will result in an IndexOutOfBoundsException when looping with increasing index.

```
@app.route('/answerSurvey', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def answerSurvey():
    answers_user = request.form.getlist('answers')

    for i in range(len(answers_user)-1, -1, -1):
        if answers_user[i] == '1':
            del answers_user[i + 1]

    ...

    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class QuestionAnswers(db.Model):
    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    questions = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    answer = db.Column(db.booleen, primary_key=False)


@app.route('/answerSurvey', method=['GET','POST'])
def questions():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        question_id = request.form.get('q.id')
        questions = request.form.get('q')
        answer = request.form.get('checkbox')

        db.session.commit()
    else:
        //do something
```

I'm assuming you're using the flask's default database, SQL Alchemy. This is a relational database, which means data is organised into rows and columns. With that said, your query is to save the value of a checkbox. The possibilities for data can be simplified to checked, unchecked, or true or false.

So all you have to do is create a data type booleen in your model database, set it to false (unchecked) when the user interacts and updates it, and it will change to true when the user interacts and updates it.

Now you must construct a route, or, to put it another way, an address where this value transfer will take place.
To post data, you must add POST in methods. You can get all the html tags from which data must be taken and send them to the variable as in the database by getting all the html tags from which data must be taken and sending them to the variable as in the database by getting all the html tags from which data must be taken and sending them to the variable as in the database by getting all the html tags from which data must be taken and sending them to the variable

To do so, your data must be received in the form of a mutable dictionary.
If an error happens, it is mutable, which means it may be changed/updated later.

```
error immutibaleMultiDict
```

use this to make your data mutable

```
data = request.form.to_dict()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I did not quite understand all of it, since there are a few repetitions of words. I am as well storing the answers in a separate database table and have linked them with the belonging question with a ForeignKey.
In your answer you are assuming the answer of a question is a column of the question table. I did not post the two classes because I was thinking it was clear when posting the html code. 
I have to admit, if I would use your type of questions, it would be a solid answer, so thanks for that.